# SQL syntax exception

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner to MYSQL and want to find out why i am getting a sql syntax exception for the below query:

```
select a.file_id 
   from FILE_XFER_TRACKING_DETAIL a,  FILE_XFER_TRACKING_HEADER b 
where  b.transaction_id = a.transaction_id 
and  b.interface_id =? 
and  a.file_name =? 
and  a.status = 'InProcess' 
and   a.update_time > sysdate- 0.003472222222222222 
and a.file_id <> ?
and b.direction = ?
```

In mysql workbench, in the editor i see the syntax error at `and b.interface_id=?` . I am a beginner and not sure how to fix it,

Comment: replace `?` for actual values

Comment: Can you give the exact syntax errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put an actual value where the `?` is. For example `and b.interface_id = 100`

And so on for the rest of them.

Comment: It would be nice if people left a reason for a down-vote... It's not all the issues in the query, but it does address one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the reference to the bareword **`sysdate`** is valid syntax for **Oracle**, but it's invalid for **MySQL**.

In MySQL, to return the current datetime, you'd want to reference the function `SYSDATE()`, or the function `NOW()`.

Subtracting a numeric value from a `DATE` expression is valid in Oracle; but it's not valid in MySQL.

The particular numeric value specified in your query (`0.003472222222222222`) would be interpreted by Oracle as the fractional part of day, essentially equivalent to 5 minutes. ( = 1/24/60 * 5 )

In MySQL, to do the equivalent, you'd want something like:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL -5 MINUTE
```

---

Also, ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause. (The comma join operator is still valid syntax, it's just very outdated and the improved syntax has been available for a long time.)

```
  FROM FILE_XFER_TRACKING_DETAIL a
  JOIN FILE_XFER_TRACKING_HEADER b
    ON b.transaction_id = a.transaction_id 
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You've copied this from some code where the SQL was meant to be a a prepared statement.

The question marks `?` need to be replaced with values for comparison in you where clause.

```
 where  b.transaction_id = a.transaction_id 
    and  b.interface_id = '<your value here>'
    and  a.file_name = '<your value here>' 
    and  a.status = '<your value here>' 
    and   a.update_time > sysdate- 0.003472222222222222 
    and a.file_id <> '<your value here>'
    and b.direction = ''<your value here>'
```

Comment: **`sysdate - 0.03472`** is valid Oracle syntax, but it's invalid in MySQL. In MySQL, we'd replace that with something like: **`NOW() + INTERVAL -5 MINUTE`**

Comment: ah, I thought it was a unique column name

Comment: That possibility totally escaped me; I'm just so used to qualifying _EVERY_ column reference with a table alias, I forget that you can actually reference columns _WITHOUT_ qualifying them. That, and I'd never consider naming a column "sysdate".  If `sysdate` _is_ in fact a column name, and the datatype of the column is something other than DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, then what I said in my previous comment doesn't apply. (The OP query just looks an awful lot like old-school Oracle syntax.)